# Most Efficient Way to Add Hundreds of Large Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask, stock

I am running into an issue when creating a very large dataframe (400 Million+ rows, consisting of minute data from Jan 04, 2021 - Dec 21, 2021 of active stocks on the NASDAQ which is currently at 4833).

I have built a backtester to test algorithms on this data by vectorization. I did all my development on a dataframe made up of 50 stocks with the same timeframe, the dataframe was 4 million+ rows and had no issues.

Now I am trying to scale up to run this on an exchange worth of stocks, and the first issue I am having is running out of memory (computer has 20GB). Here is my code to build up the large dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from alpaca_trade_api.rest import REST, TimeFrame
import os

api_key = os.getenv('ALPACA_API_KEY')
api_secret = os.getenv('ALPACA_SECRET_KEY')
base_url = 'https://paper-api.alpaca.markets'
api = REST(api_key, api_secret, base_url)

def minute_data(start, end, stocks):
    total_data = []

    for stock in stocks:
    
        minutes= api.get_bars(stock, TimeFrame.Minute, start=start, end=end, 
        adjustment='raw').df
        minutes = minutes[['symbol', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 
        'relative_volume', 'vwap']]
        minutes = squeeze_dataframe(minutes)
        total_data.append(minutes)


    #combine all dataframes into one
    total_data = pd.concat(total_data)
```

I make a call for each individual stock which returns a dataframe, I run a data type function on the dataframe to reduce it's size for each column and then append it to a list. Then concatenate the list once the for loop is complete. No problems in the for loop, but when it tries to concatenate the massive list I get this error "numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError:"

I am assuming that the list is just too large for the concatenate to process it all. I have been looking into this and some say to use a dicionary and turn that into a pandas dataframe or use Dask.

Playing with big data is new to me so I am looking for the most efficient/proper way to go about returning a large dataframe that is timestamp indexed from adding the thousands of individual stock dataframes together . Any suggestions on how to go about this would help alot.

Comment: maybe use csv.reader to append line-by-line information to the output file? it would be time-consuming, but since it writes 1 line at a time, it most certainly won't fail due to a memory issue unless you run out of storage space.

Comment: 400mm rows * 4833 stocks is just not do-able on a single machine. Assuming each number is a float, it's 32bit of memory per number, you need around 64 *thousand* GB of memory.  Do you need everything in a single dataframe or can you do your work in batches?

Comment: edit: bits vs bytes. u need 8 thousand GB of memory. Still!

Comment: It's roughly 85,000 (rows for one year worth of a stock data) x 4833 = 410 million

Comment: So the end result would be a large dataframe that has roughly 400millon+ rows. I can also reduce the time-frame of data further reducing the over size, but my main goal is to have a dataframe that has all the stocks in it, and each stock has enough data to provide value to the backtest.

Comment: [Use a tool built to scale - don't reinvent this wheel](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html)

Comment: @CJR, could you provide some code on how to use Dask.

Comment: https://examples.dask.org/dataframe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tate I think this is a nice use for Dask. In addition to @Sultan's overview of how the data engineering might work, here's an example for how you can use Dask to read in the individual dataframes and combine them. It is more pseudocode than being directly copy-pasteable, because I didn't set up an Alpaca account:

```py
import dask
from dask import delayed
import dask.dataframe as dd


@delayed
def get_bars(stock, start_time, end_time):
    minutes = api.get_bars(stock, TimeFrame.Minute, start=start, end=end, 
        adjustment='raw').df
    return minutes

# create a list of delayed objects, one for each stock you need
delayed_list = [get_bars(stock, start_time, end_time) for stock in stocks]
# returns Dask dataframe for all stocks
ddf = dd.from_delayed(delayed_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Dask does sound like an appropriate tool here, but it might be a good idea to first make sure the data is structured in an efficient way. Given the size of the data you might want to either use a database (so stream your API calls into a database, which can later be queried by `dask` or some other tool) or alternatively store the data on a stock-by-stock basis, ideally using some thing like `parquet`, because it will allow saving data with time indexing.

For example, if the function in question can be refactored for a single stock, then the following could be a pseudo-code to save the data:

```py
def save_data(start, end, stock):
   df = minute_data(start, end, stock) # note stock rather than stocks
   df = df.set_index('time_variable')
   df.to_parquet(f"some_path/{stock}/{start}-{end}.parquet", index=True)
```

The above procedure can be parallelised (possibly with `dask`) to download the data in parallel.

Once the data is downloaded, the data could be downloaded lazily:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
ddfA = dd.read_parquet("some_path/stock_A/*parquet")
ddfB = dd.read_parquet("some_path/stock_B/*parquet")

# if the dataframes are aligned, one could merge them efficiently
ddf_2_stocks = dd.merge(ddfA, ddfB, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

# downstream analysis could be performed with dask or pandas
# for pandas row-based calculations, check map_partitions
# https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html
```